# Inequality $\frac{1}{2028}<\frac{a}{2027+a}+\frac{b}{2026+b²}+\frac{c}{2024+c⁴}+\frac{d}{2020+d^8}<\frac{1}{2019}$

Tags: inequality

Given:

$a+b+c+d=1$

$a,b,c,d∈R_+$

I want to prove or refute the following inequality:

$\frac{1}{2028}<\frac{a}{2027+a}+\frac{b}{2026+b²}+\frac{c}{2024+c⁴}+\frac{d}{2020+d^8}<\frac{1}{2019}$

This is my first inequality proving, and I've not any idea how to do that. Could you give me some tip and advise book for the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0\leq a, b, c, d\leq 1$, we see
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{2027+a}+\frac{b}{2026+b²}+\frac{c}{2024+c⁴}+\frac{d}{2020+d^8}
> & \frac{a}{2027+1}+\frac{b}{2026+1}+\frac{c}{2024+1}+\frac{d}{2020+1}\\
\geq & \frac{a}{2028}+\frac{b}{2028}+\frac{c}{2028}+\frac{d}{2028}\\
=& \frac{a+b+c+d}{2028}=\frac{1}{2028},
\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{2027+a}+\frac{b}{2026+b²}+\frac{c}{2024+c⁴}+\frac{d}{2020+d^8}
< & \frac{a}{2027}+\frac{b}{2026}+\frac{c}{2024}+\frac{d}{2020}\\
\leq & \frac{a}{2020}+\frac{b}{2020}+\frac{c}{2020}+\frac{d}{2020}\\
=& \frac{a+b+c+d}{2020}=\frac{1}{2020}<\frac{1}{2019}.
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

Show that all the denominators are bounded between $2027+a$ and $2020$.  For the left one, reduce the numbers in the middle by replacing the denominators by the larger $2027+a$.  For the right one, increase the numbers in the middle by replacing the denominators with the smaller $2020$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{a}{2027+a} > \frac{a}{2028}$, $\frac{b}{2026+b^2} > \frac{b}{2028}$,$\frac{b}{2024+c^4} > \frac{c}{2028}$, $\frac{b}{2020+d^4} > \frac{d}{2028}$ for all $a,b,c,d \in (0,1)$.

Likewise, note that $\frac{a}{2027+a} < \frac{a}{2019}$, $\frac{b}{2026+b^2} > \frac{b}{2019}$,$\frac{b}{2024+c^4} > \frac{c}{2019}$, $\frac{b}{2020+d^4} > \frac{d}{2019}$ for all $a,b,c,d \in (0,1)$.

Then use the fact that $a+b+c+d=1$ to conclude.